# Php gd выравнивание многострочного текста по середине

Tags: gd, форматирование, php, изображения, текст

Получается выравнивание по правому краю, и если для однострочного текста я могу самостоятельно задать отступы (**$padLeft** - отступ слева), то для двух и более строк никак, для вывода текста пользуюсь стандартным вызовом:

> ```
> imagettftext($im, 12, 0, $padLeft, $padTop, $textColor, $font, "строка1
> ```
>
> \nстрока2");

Comment: Работа с текстом в изображениях - это всегда боль, конкретно с gd надо вызывать [imagettfbbox()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagettfbbox.php) и мерять ширину результата. Когда у меня встала задача переноса строк и урезания по длине с подстановкой многоточия, я тупо реализовал это через количество символов. С пакетом [imagine/imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine) это должно быть попроще, там вроде есть Font::box() или что-то такое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выводите и выравнивайте каждую строку отдельно. Рабочий пример такой ровнялки [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imagettftext.php#76871):

Answer (score 2):

```
function text_center ($im, $str, font, $textColor, $pad_left, $padTop, $width_text, $font_size ) 
{
    $arr = explode(' ', $str); $ret = "";
    foreach($arr as $word){ 
        $tmp_string = $ret.' '.$word;
        $testbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $tmp_string);
        if($testbox[2] > $width_text) $ret.=($ret==""?"":"\n").$word; 
        else $ret.=($ret==""?"":" ").$word;
     }
    $arr = explode("\n", $ret);
foreach($arr as $str){
    $testbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $str);// Размер строки 
    $left_x = round(($width_text - ($testbox[2] - $testbox[0]))/2);
    imagettftext($im, $font_size, 0, $left_x +$pad_left, ($padTop), $textColor, $font, $str);
    $padTop=$padTop+ $font_size*1.5;
    }
}
```